# How to get tweets data that contain multiple keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, stream, tweepy

I'm trying to accumulate tweets data by using these typical codes. As you can see I attempt to track tweets containing 'UniversalStudios', 'Disneyland'  OR 'Los Angeles'. But in fact what I really want to get are tweets that contain these keywords "UniversalStudios", "Disneyland" AND "LosAngeles" altogether. Can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

```
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = TextBlob(all_data["text"])

        #Add the 'sentiment data to all_data
        #all_data['sentiment'] = tweet.sentiment

        #print(tweet)
        #print(tweet.sentiment)

        # Open json text file to save the tweets
        with open('tweets.json', 'a') as tf:
            # Write a new line
            tf.write('\n')

            # Write the json data directly to the file
            json.dump(all_data, tf)
            # Alternatively: tf.write(json.dumps(all_data))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(languages = ['en'], track=['UniversalStudios','Disneyland', "LosAngeles"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Twitter's API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters) (see "track") mentions you need to have **spaces** between the phrases to mean ANDs (commas are ORs). I'm not sure how the library you're using handles it, but my bet would be:

```
track=['UniversalStudios Disneyland LosAngeles']
```

The quote from the docs:

> By this model, you can think of commas as logical ORs, while spaces are equivalent to logical ANDs (e.g. ‘the twitter’ is the AND twitter, and ‘the,twitter’ is the OR twitter).

Comment: Thanks for your help!